# nodejs empty document fs.writeFile/appendFile

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm new to writing a chat log bot with nodejs. And it works pretty good right now. Except after a few hours. 
The bot creates a document for each user that types something if such a document doesn't already exist for the user, if it exists then it will put it in that file.
Here is my code:

```
fs.open('logs/' + channel.substr(1) + '/' + user.username +'.txt','r',function(err,fd){
    if (err && err.code=='ENOENT') 
    {
    fs.writeFile('logs/' + channel.substr(1) + '/' + user.username +'.txt', '[' + 'GMT' + moment().format('Z ') + moment().format('D.M.YYYY H:mm:ss')  + '] ' + user.username + ': ' + message + '\n', function (err) {});
    } else {
    fs.appendFile('logs/' + channel.substr(1) + '/' + user.username +'.txt', '[' + 'GMT' + moment().format('Z ') + moment().format('D.M.YYYY H:mm:ss')  + '] ' + user.username + ': ' + message + '\n', function(){});    
    }
  });
```

The problem is after a few hours of users chatting the documents of new users end up empty. Older chatters that kept chatting will not have new lines added to their files aswell.

I'm using the "graceful-fs" module because I was hoping it would fix the issue, but I don't think the module has changed much.
What am I doing wrong? Why do my new .txt's end up empty (0 kb size)

Comment: Any chance `err` is not empty and not `ENOENT`?

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file descriptor, you must eventually close it (`fs.close`).  Every time you run that bit of code, you leak a file descriptor.  Each process is limited to a set number of file descriptors, depending on your OS and settings.  When you run out, no operations that require opening a file will succeed.

Comment: hmm makes sense. The documentation looks like this fs.close(fd, callback), how would I implement that in my code? just a simple fs.close() ? because that is crashing for me

Comment: @user3648229 You might want `fs.closeSync(fd)`, which doesn't require dealing with a callback.  Just pass it that `fd` variable. Alternatively, use `fs.stat` instead of `fs.open` which will give you the information about whether a file exists without giving you a file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
fs.appendFile(filename, data, {flag: "a+"}, callback)
```

This will append to the file if it exists, otherwise it will create it with the given data.

Comment: thanks, this atleast cleans up the code a lot. I'll see if it fixes the problem I have